# C - char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[200]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, header-files, double-pointer

For a C programming assignment, I am trying to write several header files to check the syntax of a so called "X Programming Language". I have started very recently and I am writing the first header file. Here is the code I've written yet:

```
#ifndef _DeclarationsChecker_h_
#define _DeclarationsChecker_h_



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT 200
#define CODE_LINE_LIMIT 1000


void checkDeclarations(char **code, int num_lines) {


    char *currentLine;

    for (int currentLineNum = 0; currentLineNum < num_lines; currentLineNum++) {

        if (code[currentLineNum] != NULL) {

            currentLine = code[currentLineNum];

            char (**tokenized)[LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT];

            for (int i = 0; i < strlen(currentLine); i++) {

                tokenized[i] = strtok(currentLine, " ");

                if (tokenized[i] == NULL) 
                    break;
            }

            char *currentToken;

            for (int i = 0; i < LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT; i++) {

                currentToken = tokenized[i];

                if (strcmp("***", currentToken)) 
                    break;

                char (*nextToken) = tokenized[i + 1];

                if (strcmp("global", currentToken)) {

                    if (!strcmp("character", nextToken) && !strcmp("integer", nextToken) && !strcmp("double", nextToken) && !strcmp("string", nextToken)) {
                        printf("Declarations: unknown data type %s at line %d", nextToken, currentLineNum);
                    }

                }

                if (strcmp("character", currentToken) || strcmp("integer", currentToken) || strcmp("double", currentToken) || strcmp("string", currentToken)) {

                    char *functionName = strtok(nextToken, '(');

                    if (strcmp("character", functionName) || strcmp("integer", functionName) || strcmp("double", functionName) || strcmp("string", functionName) || strcmp("while", functionName) || strcmp("if", functionName) || strcmp("else", functionName) || strcmp("global", functionName) || strcmp("equal", functionName) || strcmp("nequal", functionName) || strcmp("return", functionName)) {

                        printf("Declarations: naming violation of %s at line %d", functionName, currentLineNum);
                    }

                    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(functionName); i++) {

                        if (!isalnum(functionName[i]) && (functionName[i] != '_') && (functionName[i] != '?')) {

                            printf("Declarations: naming violation of %s at line %d", functionName, currentLineNum);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}

#endif
```

I got several compiling warnings, I will add the warnings to the end, and when I try to launch the program, it immediately gives a "the program crashed" error, but I think it may be because of the not yet written header files. What can I do to get rid of the errors I got? Thank you for the answers, any help will be greatly appreciated. (Note that I'm new to C and I did not quite grasp the notion of interchangability between arrays and pointers and double pointers (e.g. : **ptr) )

```
...\declarationschecker.h(30): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
...\declarationschecker.h(32): warning C4047: '=': 'char (*)[200]' differs in levels of indirection from 'char *'
...\declarationschecker.h(42): warning C4047: '=': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[200]'
...\declarationschecker.h(59): warning C4047: 'function': 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
...\declarationschecker.h(59): warning C4024: 'strtok': different types for formal and actual parameter 2
...\declarationschecker.h(66): warning C4018: '<': signed/unsigned mismatch
...\declarationschecker.h(47): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[200]'
```

The main c file which needs the headers is posted below:

```
#include "CodeReader.h"
#include "BracketsChecker.h"
#include "DeclarationsChecker.h"
#include "StatementsChecker.h"
#include "SSAChecker.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Please provide X code file name\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    char **code = readCode(argv[1]);
    int  num_lines = getCodeNumLines();

    checkBrackets(code, num_lines);
    checkDeclarations(code, num_lines);
    checkProgramStatements(code, num_lines);
    checkSSA(code, num_lines);

    cleanMemory(code);

    int terminalHung; scanf("%d", &terminalHung);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the posted code is in a header file?  Are there any .c files?  You need at least one .C for this to build.  If it is a .c, then you have failed to include the error you got when you attempted to build.  It would be something similar to _Undefined symbol '_main' referenced in ..._.

Comment: Yes, this is a header file, used by a main c file. The c file calls the function "checkDeclarations" which is defined in this header file, which I'm trying to write, with the argument of a (**code) which is an array of strings, the lines of the code written with the X language, and an integer argument which is the number of the lines.

Comment: Okay, then for starters, it is not typical to place functions in a header file.  you need to show how this function is called, i.e. how you prepared `char **code` before sending it, etc.  and include a main function so that people trying to help can compile and build your [mcve].

Comment: Okay, thank you for your answer, ı will edit the post and add the main file, also I would like to note that the main c file is provided to us and we are asked to implement four header files which are already created and empty.

Comment: Note, that because there are functions in your post that do not include the definitions (eg. `readCode()`, et.al.) your code still does not provide a [mcve].  But I have edited my answer below to attempt addressing comments below the post.  If you need any further help, post another question, be specific, and include the code necessary for someone to compile what you provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, without having access to the rest of your project (I assume there are several other files containing some of the functions you reference in your post), it is not possible to know how exactly you are creating your *code generator*, limiting suggestions to syntactical issues.

Explanation of following errors from your post is in both comments below, and in-line comments in code at bottom:
[image]

First, In your edited section, I cannot see what the function `readCode()` is because you did not include it, but if it does not create memory then the variable `code` cannot be used.

After declaring `char (**tokenized)[LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT];` you try to use the zeroth array element of a `char **` without first creating memory. At best, your program would crash during run-time, even worse, it would appear to work.  This is referred to as *[Undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)*, or *[Unspecified behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unspecified_behavior)*.  ( read up on how to use  *[malloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm)* ). Because you are preparing storage for a collection of strings, you will only need two diminsions, not three.  Either a `char *[]` or a `char **` would work.  In either case, these must be initialized and memory created before use. However, since you already know max number of lines and max length of lines simply declare and use: `char tokenized[CODE_LINE_LIMIT][LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT];`.

Also, declare `char *token = 0;` to use with strtok.  (see comments for reason)

Also, declare multiply used variables once (such as `i`. see comments for reason)

For the rest, again, review in-line comments to see how the previous errors/warning have been addressed in your code:

```
static void checkDeclarations(char **code, int num_lines) 
{

    char *token = 0;//use with strtok
    char *currentLine;
    char tokenized[CODE_LINE_LIMIT][LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT] = {{0}};
    int i, len;  // declare multiply used variables once

    for (int currentLineNum = 0; currentLineNum < num_lines; currentLineNum++) {

        if (code[currentLineNum] != NULL) {

            currentLine = code[currentLineNum];

            //char (*tokenized)[LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT] = {0};
            len = strlen(currentLine);
            for( i = 0; i< len; i++ ) // corrected
            //for (int i = 0; i < strlen(currentLine); i++)  // don't do string comparison's in a loop
            {                                              // and avoid comparisons of different types
                                                           // return of strlen() is an unsigned int
                token =  strtok(currentLine, " ");

                if (token == NULL) break;
                else strcpy(tokenized[i], token);
            }

            char *currentToken;

            //for (int i = 0; i < LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT; i++) {  // shadow declaration of previously declared variable
            for ( i = 0; i < LINE_LENGTH_LIMIT; i++) {       // corrected

                currentToken = tokenized[i];

                if (strcmp("***", currentToken)) 
                    break;

                char (*nextToken) = tokenized[i + 1];

                if (strcmp("global", currentToken)) {

                    if (!strcmp("character", nextToken) && !strcmp("integer", nextToken) && !strcmp("double", nextToken) && !strcmp("string", nextToken)) {
                        printf("Declarations: unknown data type %s at line %d", nextToken, currentLineNum);
                    }

                }

                if (strcmp("character", currentToken) || strcmp("integer", currentToken) || strcmp("double", currentToken) || strcmp("string", currentToken)) {

                    //char *functionName = strtok(nextToken, '(');  // strtok 2nd argument requires a string, not an integer
                    char *functionName = strtok(nextToken, "(");  // corrected
                // note: calling this in a loop will be a problem.  either Declare 'functionName' at top of function
                // or use 'token', already declared

                    if (strcmp("character", functionName) || strcmp("integer", functionName) || strcmp("double", functionName) || strcmp("string", functionName) || strcmp("while", functionName) || strcmp("if", functionName) || strcmp("else", functionName) || strcmp("global", functionName) || strcmp("equal", functionName) || strcmp("nequal", functionName) || strcmp("return", functionName)) {

                        printf("Declarations: naming violation of %s at line %d", functionName, currentLineNum);
                    }

                    //for (int i = 0; i < strlen(functionName); i++) { // "i" has already been declared above
                    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++) { // corrected

                        if (!isalnum(functionName[i]) && (functionName[i] != '_') && (functionName[i] != '?')) {

                            printf("Declarations: naming violation of %s at line %d", functionName, currentLineNum);

                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

***Edit to address question in comment...***
The following may already be known to you, but your post gives no indication, so I am offering the following just in case:

Before assigning a string to a `char *str` (eg. via use of `strcpy` or `strcat`, etc.) you must create memory:

```
int desiredStrLen  = 80;
char *str = calloc(desiredStrLen + 1, 1);
if(str)// test return of calloc before trusting it worked
{
    //use str 
    ...
    free(str); // always, when finished with any dynamically allocated memory, free it.
```

For a collection of strings (eg. required when reading lines of a file) you can create memory for a set of strings.  Once determining the number of lines as well as the longest line in a file, you can create memory sufficient to copy each line read from the file into a string:

```
char **currentLine = Create2DStr(numLines, longestLine);
if(strings)
{
    /// use currentLine (in your loop)
    ...
    strcpy(currentLine[i], code[currentLineNum]);
    ...
    // when finished with string collection, free it.
    free2DStr(&strings, numLines);
```

The functions I am using above can be implemented in many ways.  I use the following:

```
char ** Create2DStr(ssize_t numStrings, ssize_t maxStrLen)
{
    int i;
    char **str = {0};
    str = calloc(numStrings, sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      str[i] = calloc(maxStrLen + 1, 1);
    }
    return str;
}

void free2DStr(char *** str, ssize_t numStrings)
{
    int i;
    if(!(*str)) return;
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
            free((*str)[i]);
            (*str)[i] = NULL;
    }
    free((*str));
    (*str) = NULL;
}
```

Comment: The function readCode() is implemented in a different header file which is provided to us, if you want to take a look at it, I can edit the post and include it as well but I don't think there would be a problem caused by it. Thank you so much for your effort and detailed answer.

Comment: Thanks, not necessary.  I think the in-line comments and suggestions should get you at least beyond the errors/warnings in your code.  But since you are just getting started, do not forget to become familiar with memory allocation techniques (including freeing), and also important, if you do not have to use dynamic memory, don't.  Refer to your C book to become generally familiar with all the standard functions.

Comment: Currently, I'm debugging the code and sometimes I get the error while it is trying to assign strings to char* variables. Should I use strcpy() for string assignments instead of equal sign? Or do you have a better alternative in mind?

Comment: Yes, always use string functions (i.e. in this case `strcpy` or `strcat`, etc) to assign strings.  see  `else strcpy(tokenized[i], token);` in my answer.  `=` is only for numeric, and in some cases pointer assignments.

Comment: Based on your advice, ı tried to change the line currentToken = tokenized[i] to a strcpy() call but when I try to execute the program, it immediately crashes and gives an unhandled exception warning. When I debugged, it seems that strcpy() doesn't work and the value of currentToken stays NULL so when I try to take its length with strlen() it crashes. What do you think the problem would be?

Comment: @TrkDgnr - The posted code in this answer only contains what was necessary do to address your questions about warnings/errors, it does not attempt to go beyond that. This is because I have no idea what you are attempting to do, and because you have not provided an Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, it is not likely that anyone can. In any case, see edit in my post for example of how to create, and use memory... (in a few minutes)